# Javafx Binding font property with scene framework

Tags: javafx, fonts, binding, size, fxml

I am currently writing a sudoku solver/game application. I am however struggling to get my application to manage the size of text depending on the size of its container using binding. I am using a scene framework that controls when different FXML files and their respective controllers are loaded and then shown to the user.

**The objective:** I would like to accomplish is when the choose level FXML is displayed I would like it so that the text within the gridpane get bigger/smaller when the size of the gridpane changes.

**The problem:** I have encountered is that I cannot find a method of binding text for any given control when a different FXML is shown on the scene. I have tried using the initialize method within the controllers, but the problem there is that the scene framework loads and initializes all the FXML and controller files when the application is started.

The running order of my program is as follows:

1. Main Menu
2. Difficulty selection
3. Choose level
4. Play Screen

Thank you in advance, as this is my first time posting on stack overflow.

This is the relevant code I am working with:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Application {

public static String mainMenu = "Main Menu";
public static String mainMenuFXML = "/FXML/MainMenu.fxml";
public static String levelDifficulty = "Difficulty Selection";
public static String levelDifficultyFXML = "/FXML/LevelDifficulty.fxml";
public static String chooseLevel = "Level Selection";
public static String chooseLevelFXML = "/FXML/ChooseLevel.fxml";
public static String playScreen = "PLay Screen";
public static String playScreenFXML = "/FXML/PlayScreen.fxml";

//Global Variable to be accessed across all classes
//To be used to determine which scenes are loaded in the HashMap and also which scene has been set
public static SceneFramework mainController = new SceneFramework();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    //Only the main menu scene is needed to be loaded at the start
    mainController.loadScene(Main.mainMenu, Main.mainMenuFXML);
    mainController.setScene(Main.mainMenu);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(mainController);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    launch(args);
}
}
```

**SceneFramework.java**

```
package Controller;


import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class SceneFramework extends StackPane{

    //Constructor for the class
    public SceneFramework(){
        //The keyword super, overrides methods from the superclass
        super();
    }

    //This HashMap is used to hold the screens(scenes) to be used within the application
    protected HashMap<String, Node> scenes = new HashMap<>();

    //Adds the selected scene to the HashMap
    public void addScene(String title, Node scene) {
        scenes.put(title, scene);
    }

    //Returns the Node with the specified title for use within application
    public Node getScene(String title) {
        return scenes.get(title);
    }

    //Removes the selected scene from the framework
    public boolean unloadScene(String title){
        if(scenes.remove(title) == null){
            System.out.println("Scene cannot be located or it doesn't exist");
            return false;
        } else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean loadScene(String title, String resource){
        //encase code segment in try for exception handling,
        // as resources are required to be found and then loaded into memory
        try{
            //Load FXML File
            FXMLLoader loadedFXMLFile = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resource));

            //Get Parent of scene
            Parent loadScene = loadedFXMLFile.load();

            //Get the Controller class of the parent
            SetSceneParent sceneController = (loadedFXMLFile.getController());

            //Method of making sure every scene knows who it's parent is
            sceneController.setSceneParent(this);

            //Add scene to HashMap
            addScene(title, loadScene);
            return true;

        }catch (Exception e){
            //If FXML resource can't be loaded then generate this
            System.out.println("Could't load FXML file");
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Method for showing scenes
    //If one scenes if wanting to be shown then it is added to the root
    //If multiple scenes are wanting to be loaded then the first scene is removed and the new scene is then displayed
    public boolean setScene(final String title){
        //Check to see if scene can be found
        if(scenes.get(title) != null) {
            if(!getChildren().isEmpty()){

                getChildren().remove(0);
                getChildren().add(0 ,scenes.get(title));

            }else{
                    getChildren().add(scenes.get(title));
            }
            return true;
        } else{
            System.out.println("Scene not located!!!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**SetSceneParent.java**

```
package Controller;

import Controller.SceneFramework;

public interface SetSceneParent {

   void setSceneParent(SceneFramework sceneParent);
}
```

**ChooseLevelController.java**

```
package Controller;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class ChooseLevelController implements Initializable, SetSceneParent {

    @FXML
    public Label lblLevelSelection, lblLevel1, lblLevel2, lblLevel3, lblLevel4, lblLevel5, lblLevel6, lblLevel7, lblLevel8, lblLevel9, lblLevel10; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
    public Button backButton;
    public GridPane gridPaneCenter;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        //Assert code is to be used in debugging making sure references to files and their elements are correct
        assert lblLevel1 != null : "fx:id=\"lblLevel1\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'ChooseLevel.fxml'.";
        assert lblLevel2 != null : "fx:id=\"lblLevel2\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'ChooseLevel.fxml'.";
        assert lblLevel3 != null : "fx:id=\"lblLevel3\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'ChooseLevel.fxml'.";
        assert lblLevel4!= null : "fx:id=\"lblLevel4\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'ChooseLevel.fxml'.";
        assert lblLevel5 != null : "fx:id=\"lblLevel5\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'ChooseLevel.fxml'.";
        assert lblLevel6 != null : "fx:id=\"lblLevel6\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'ChooseLevel.fxml'.";
        assert lblLevel7 != null : "fx:id=\"lblLevel7\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'ChooseLevel.fxml'.";
        assert lblLevel8 != null : "fx:id=\"lblLevel8\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'ChooseLevel.fxml'.";
        assert lblLevel9 != null : "fx:id=\"lblLevel9\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'ChooseLevel.fxml'.";
        assert lblLevel10 != null : "fx:id=\"lblLevel10\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'ChooseLevel.fxml'.";

    }

    @Override
    public void setSceneParent(SceneFramework screenParent) {
        //Sets the parent of the scene by using the global variable of the class SceneFramework
        Main.mainController = screenParent;
    }

    //Logic code
    @FXML
    public void mouseClickedLevelLabel() {

        //Load the play screen when any Label is pressed
        lblLevel1.setOnMouseClicked(e -> handleLabelClick(1));
        lblLevel2.setOnMouseClicked(e -> handleLabelClick(2));
        lblLevel3.setOnMouseClicked(e -> handleLabelClick(3));
        lblLevel4.setOnMouseClicked(e -> handleLabelClick(4));
        lblLevel5.setOnMouseClicked(e -> handleLabelClick(5));
        lblLevel6.setOnMouseClicked(e -> handleLabelClick(6));
        lblLevel7.setOnMouseClicked(e -> handleLabelClick(7));
        lblLevel8.setOnMouseClicked(e -> handleLabelClick(8));
        lblLevel9.setOnMouseClicked(e -> handleLabelClick(9));
        lblLevel10.setOnMouseClicked(e -> handleLabelClick(10));
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleBackButtonAction() {
        //On clicking of the back button
        //The user is taken to the level difficulty scene

        Main.mainController.loadScene(Main.levelDifficulty, Main.levelDifficultyFXML);
        Main.mainController.setScene(Main.levelDifficulty);
        Main.mainController.unloadScene(Main.chooseLevel);

    }

    private void handleLabelClick(int levelSelected){
        SelectionStatus.setLevelStatus(levelSelected);
        Main.mainController.loadScene(Main.playScreen, Main.playScreenFXML);
        Main.mainController.setScene(Main.playScreen);
        Main.mainController.unloadScene(Main.chooseLevel);
    }



}
```

**ChooseLevel.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller.ChooseLevelController">
   <center>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <GridPane fx:id="gridPaneCenter" alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1500.0" prefHeight="242.0" prefWidth="475.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="137.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
                <RowConstraints maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="138.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <Label fx:id="lblLevel1" onMousePressed="#mouseClickedLevelLabel" text="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="lblLevel2" onMouseClicked="#mouseClickedLevelLabel" onMousePressed="#mouseClickedLevelLabel" text="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="lblLevel3" onMousePressed="#mouseClickedLevelLabel" text="3" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="lblLevel4" onMousePressed="#mouseClickedLevelLabel" text="4" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="lblLevel5" onMousePressed="#mouseClickedLevelLabel" text="5" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="lblLevel6" onMouseClicked="#mouseClickedLevelLabel" onMousePressed="#mouseClickedLevelLabel" text="6" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="lblLevel7" onMousePressed="#mouseClickedLevelLabel" text="7" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="lblLevel8" onMousePressed="#mouseClickedLevelLabel" text="8" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="lblLevel9" onMousePressed="#mouseClickedLevelLabel" text="9" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="lblLevel10" onMousePressed="#mouseClickedLevelLabel" text="10" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </GridPane>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </center>
   <top>
      <GridPane fx:id="gridPaneTop">
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="207.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="20.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="207.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="58.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="207.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="105.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="451.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="418.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="backButton" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleBackButtonAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="0.0" text="Back" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" />
            <Separator prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="73.0" visible="false" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Label fx:id="lblLevelSelection" text="Level Selection" underline="true" GridPane.columnIndex="3">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Separator prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="73.0" visible="false" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </top>
   <bottom>
      <Region prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </bottom>
   <left>
      <HBox>
         <children>
            <Region maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="50.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </left>
   <right>
      <HBox>
         <children>
            <Region maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="50.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </right>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to run your code, but failed. All i got was a white screen (after changing some stuff to make it run and load the correct fxml at all).
I gave up.

---

So here is my GUESS as to what you are trying to accomplish:

When you resize your screen you want the font size to scale with it.

---

- Add a listener to the width property
- In the handler you use the changed width and height of the window/pane/object/w.e. to calculate your new font size
- Set the new font size

---

**Edit**: If you post a ton of code, that does not compile and run on its own (as in: minimal example), please at least point to the part of the code, that does not work - makes it easier for people to help you. As your question is now it would take quite a long time for people to find an error - and that is something most (if not all) won't do ;)

---

**Edit2:** You can also use `.setScaleX(double)` and `.setScaleY(double)` on the labels / objects that you want to scale up - you don't necessarily need to change the font size. (Depending on use case)

Answer (score 0):

Since 19

you may use like:

```java
propertyObjx.fontProperty().bind(stage.heightProperty().map(v -> Font.font("Ewert",v.floatValue()/3)));
```

cheers